# InvalidArgumentError for placeholder

Tags: tensorflow

I'm copying an example directly out of a book I am working through, and I currently getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_10' with dtype float and shape [?,2]
 [[{{node Placeholder_10}} = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,2], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

My tensors and placeholders are declared like so:

```
XOR_X = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
XOR_Y = [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0], [0.0]]

num_input = 2
num_classes = 1

x_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, num_input], name='X')
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, num_classes], name='Y')
```

And the line producing the error is here:

```
_, summary = sess.run([train_step, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={x_ : XOR_X, y_: XOR_Y})
```

What exactly is the issue here?

*for context, I attach the entire implementation here:*

```
import tensorflow as tf

XOR_X = [[0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
XOR_Y = [[0], [1], [1], [0]]
# XOR_Y = [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]

num_input = 2
num_classes = 1

x_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, num_input], name='X')
y_ = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, num_classes], name='Y')

#Model structure
H1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=x_, units=4, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
H2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=H1, units=8, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
H_OUT = tf.layers.dense(inputs=H2, units=num_classes, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)

#Define cost function
with tf.name_scope("cost") as scope:
    cost = tf.losses.log_loss( labels=y_, predictions=H_OUT)
    # Add loss to tensorboard
    tf.summary.scalar("log_loss", cost)

with tf.name_scope("train") as scope:
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cost)

merged_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

# Initialize variables(weights) and session
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()

# Configure summary to output at given directory
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./logs/xor_logs", sess.graph)
sess.run(init)

# Train loop
for step in range(10000):
    # Run train_step and merge summary op
    _, summary = sess.run([train_step, merged_summary_op], feed_dict={x_ : XOR_X, y_: XOR_Y})
    if step % 1000 == 0:
        print("Step/Epoch: {}, Loss: {}".format(step, sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x_ : XOR_X, y_: XOR_Y})))
        writer.add_summary(summary, step)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the number of sample instead of `None` in the `x_` placeholder. Also, try making these changes.

```
n_samples = len( XOR_X )
x_ = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32 , shape=[n_samples, num_input], name='X')
```